# Can't perform a math.ceiling() over a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, math

I have the following sentence:

```
b['trucks_est'] = math.ceil(b['volume'] / b['max_boxes_per_truck'])
```

Which raises this exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\HUGO~1.VIL\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12504/708959517.py in <module>
----> 1 b['trucks_est'] = math.ceil(
      2             b['volume'] / b['max_boxes_per_truck'])

~\Documents\code\Venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in wrapper(self)
    183         if len(self) == 1:
    184             return converter(self.iloc[0])
--> 185         raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
    186 
    187     wrapper.__name__ = f"__{converter.__name__}__"

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>
```

I know the problem is the `math.ceiling()` because `b['trucks_est'] = b['volume'] / b['max_boxes_per_truck']` works perfectly.

How can I perform this math operation over a pandas dataframe?

Comment: You can use `np.ceil` instead.

Comment: Or `(jb['Weight']/jb['Height']).apply(lambda x: math.ceil(x))` but no need to use slow lambda when there is a better alternative in numpy

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to do this instead:

```
b['trucks_est'] = np.ceil(b['volume'] / b['max_boxes_per_truck'])
```

link to documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ceil.html